# Axios is not placing the origin header in the request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, axios

I am using axios in react, and he is not putting the Origin header in the request, so he is giving server side cors (nodejs) problem.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({baseURL: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/node/api/', withCredentials: true});

export default api;
```

View: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTwh5.png

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.

```
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true; 
const api = axios.create({baseURL: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/node/api/'});

export default api;
```

Comment: Property assignment expected.ts(1136)

Comment: I put, still not sending the header "Origin"

Comment: @Henrique withCredentials is about to send cookies. if you want to add any header you need to add axios.create({baseURL: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/node/api/'}, {"headerxxxx":"headervaluexxxx"});

Comment: The "Origin" header cannot be sent monthly, it must be sent automatically by the browser, but this is not happening. With ajax sends, already with axios no.

Comment: Why do you want to send Origin header ?

Comment: Because of the cors policy implemented on the server, it checks from the origin header.